# Multi keystore files for MQ AMS

Tags: security, certificate, ibm-mq

I intended to use AMS to encrypt/decrypt MQ messages. I have successfully installed MQ Server v9 on server, and have implemented a client application.
My application has two users ***alice*** and ***bob***, both of them use the same *keystore.jks*.

The problem is, I have new requirement that each user should use it own certificate, channel, and queue for more secure and not cause impact to each other. That means *alice* should use *alice's private key*, and *bob* should use *bob's private key* separately when calling to MQ server.

Could you give me some ideas how to do that kind of business?

For more details, in my case the application has many users of its own, and each user should have a separate private key for calling to MQ server.

E.g:

- *customer -> calling to application -> login as alice -> use certificate_1 ->  calling to MQ server.*
- *customer -> calling to application -> login as bob -> use certificate_2 ->  calling to MQ server.*

--- Update for more detail information. I'm using Java Client for JMS library. Hope it could give some help.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your diagram, you appear to be running the "My application" under user ID appl_user and not running it as alice or as bob. Why is this? The AMS encryption is applied at the Green machine before it goes across the wire. It is on this green machine that you should have the two different user ids defined. Only if you do this can different keystores be used.

Comment: Seems like that is the only way to use different keystores. Maybe I should use another approach than AMS to secure MQ messages. Thanks a lot for your support so far.

Comment: I thought you WANTED to use different keystores? Perhaps I have misunderstood your question. Also, when you says "Seems like that is the only way ..." what do you mean by "that"? There are other ways to pick up a keystore than the user id the application is running under. You can set an environment variable to point at the keystore you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using users called alice and bob suggests you may already have seen the Quick Start Guide in Knowledge Center. However, in case you haven't, it provides a complete step-by-step walk-through of how to set up alice and bob with their own keystores and how to exchange their certificates so that they can authenticate the messages from each other.

If you have already followed one of these guides and had trouble understanding how to make separate keys and keystores, please provide more detail in your question, so we can help more directly.

[Quick Start Guide for AMS on UNIX platforms](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014700_.htm)

[Quick Start Guide for AMS on Windows platforms](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014690_.htm)

[Quick Start Guide for AMS with Java clients](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014680_.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I have read these documents already. As my understanding, by applying above guideline, my application will use **keystore.conf** of OS's user who run that application to encrypting messages. That means once the application runs, it uses the same **keystore.conf** file -> same certificates

Comment: If you have two users, alice and bob, then your application should be using the keystore.conf of the user you are running the application under, either alice or bob. If you have followed the above instructions you should have two keystore.conf files, one for alice and one for bob, each pointing to it's own keystore containing its own private key. Perhaps you could update your original question with more details of what you did so we can see where you need to do something different?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. The users your are mentioning are users of server, created by operation system. But users in my case are the application's users, these users will be used by customers :(

Comment: In the examples I pointed to, Alice and bob are the application users. The whole point of AMS is end-to-end encryption. You want the message encrypted from before it is even MQPUT by the MQ application. Perhaps you could show on your question's arrow diagram where the first MQ interaction is? And what user context you are in at that point? Perhaps the problem is that you need to use a keystone in a non-default location because of how you select your login context?

Comment: Regarding **Quick Start Guide for AMS with Java clients**, it says:
+ By running different programs under different users you can verify if the application has been properly configured -> if application is run by _alice_ -> keystore of _alice_ would be used by AMS interceptor.

Comment: You are correct - this **if application is run by alice -> keystore of alice would be used by AMS interceptor** is the pertinent sentence. Your application is run by 'appl-user'.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Windows you can test the alice and bob sample using any Windows user. Configure the keystores and certificates as described and create the keystore.conf file for alice and bob for instance in two different directories. Use two cmd.exe shells one for alice and one for bob. Set the environment variable MQS_KEYSTORE_CONF to point to the corresponding file.
For example...

cmd shell for alice:

```
set MQS_KEYSTORE_CONF=C:\Temp\mqssl\alice\keystore.conf
amqsput TEST.Q QM_VERIFY_AMS
```

cmd shell for bob:

```
set MQS_KEYSTORE_CONF=C:\Temp\mqssl\bob\keystore.conf
amqsget TEST.Q QM_VERIFY_AMS
```

This sample also works with MQ client (amqsputc, amqsgetc) using MQCHLTAB and SSL.